# Checking a field of an object in a PriorityQueue

Tags: java, priority-queue

I need to use a `PriorityQueue` to have sorted FIFO elements. The queue will contain a Message objects each one of which will have a `double timestamp` as well as an `int counter` which keeps track of how many acknowledgments have been received for that message. 
There are two types of messages - ones with the data and ones with acknowledgment. Only messages with data are to be put in a queue. I am writing a comparator which will be used to sort the queue. I will be popping only head of the queue only if it has received all acknowledgments.

The problem is that, as an acknowledgment message comes in, I need to increment the acknowledgment counter of a message for which this acknowledgment was received. For this, I need to find the message by checking a particular field of each message in queue (the sending time).

How can this be done? I thought of following:

Get an iterator and then iterate over the queue checking the particular field of each object.

This seems like brutal method to me though. Is there any better way? Can we access an object in a queue like this?

---

*NOTE*: I need to use the PriorityQueue because the functionality I am implementing (total ordered multicast in distributed system using Lamport's logical clock) needs to have an ordered queue. I can not deliver the message at the head of the queue to the application thread if it is not acknowledged by each node. Also, I cannot deliver the message which is not at the head of the queue even if it has received all acknowledgments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: Yes, we can access a `PriorityQueue` that way, since it's implementing the `Iterable`-interface.

When you think of performance issues, you could log-down the complexity by using some kind of pivot (see `Quicksort`).

If you find it somehow stupid: The most good solutions are somehow stupid, but mostly work fine.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you're using the wrong type of data structure. If you are receiving messages from a Queue (i.e. JMS or similar) then why not read the message off the queue and store the data into a more appropriate data structure like a Map (e.g. HashMap) or database if you require persistence.

When you receive the acknowledgements you can look-up the corresponding object in your Map and update the count. A map may have faster random access if that is what you require.

If you increment the acknowledgement count and it reaches the threshold of "I've now received all my acknowledgements" then you can push the message onto a new Queue for further processing if that is what you desire.

Some food for thought. Hopefully I have interpreted your question correctly.

Comment: I need to use the PriorityQueue because the functionality I am implementing (total ordered multicast in distributed system using Lamport's logical clock) needs to have an ordered queue. I can not deliver the message at the head of the queue to the application thread if it is not acknowledged by each node. Also, I cannot deliver the message which is not at the head of the queue even if it has received all acknowledgments.